# Кавказ - Закавказье, Урал - Зауралье, Алтай -?

Tags: правописание

Как правильно написать это слово? Какие будут варианты?

UPDATE:

Спасибо за ответы и комментарии. Хочу пояснить, что вопрос про орфографию, а не про географию. Сформулирую точнее:

Как писать слова, образованные от основы на **-й** (Алтай, Китай, юбилей...) с помощью приставки и суффикса [j], который на письме обычно передается через **-ье** (Закавказье, Зауралье...)?

Я понимаю, что таких слов, возможно, и не существует, или они существуют только в окказиональном употреблении, так что на данный момент вопрос чисто теоретический.

Comment: Да в общем никак, нет просто такого слова.  Скорее всего потому, что все что *за Алтаем* уже имеет свои собственные названия (Монголия, Китай, Восточный Туркестан и т.д.), и нет нужды мешать это все в одну кучу. В некоем *обобщенном* "Заалтаи" просто не возникло необходимости (возникло бы - появилось бы и слово). Для чего вам оно понадобилось, кстати?

Comment: Да ни за чем в общем-то. Вопрос про орфографию, а не про географию. Однажды мне довелось услышать окказионализм "предъюбилей-е" с тем же суффиксом [j], который пристыковывается к корню, заканчивающемуся на [j]. Мне стало интересно, как его написать. Про Алтай придумал просто, чтобы задать вопрос и при этом никак не написать само слово. :)

Comment: Ну в теории была бы какая-нибудь Заалтайщина (совсем если на вскидку) или типа того. В этом смысле лазеек в языке для таких случаев много (ну так же как мы, например, говорим Подмосковье, но не говорим Подпсковье или Подпетербужье, и наоборот). А "предъюбилей-е" это что-то из серии "победю" :).

Comment: с суффиксом **-ьe**, я думаю, образование слова невозможно по чисто фонетическим причинам, потому что он предполагает смягчение предшествующей согласной и образование порога между корнем и суффиксом, а **Й** мягкая уже сама по себе, с мягким знаком не сочетается, в связи с этим присоединение к ней суффикса приводит к его слиянию с корнем и тем самым размыванию слова

Comment: "Заалайский хребет" уже существует. Если нужно, будет и "Заал*т*айский".

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка, с фонетикой как раз проблем нет: сказать Заалта[jj]е или предъюбиле[jj]е можно. Вопрос в том, как это лучше записать.

Comment: сказать многое можно, не всё благозвучно и не всё соответствует фонетической логике, Заалтайе и предъюбилейе на слух сливаются с формой предложного падежа основ этих слов, и не воспринимаются как форма именительного падежа их самих, в том числе и по причине отсутствия у слушателя ожидания услышать подобную форму слова

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка, с совпадением с формой предложного не соглашусь: вы ведь различаете на слух Майя и мая? Да и с восприятием в контексте у меня не возникло проблемы, когда я услышал "Замечательное у нас получилось пред... юбилейе!" Видимо, именно так и следует писать такие слова, единственная претензия к этому способу - нарушение морфологического принципа орфографии (ье против йе). Плюс - наличие прецендентов типа Майя, секвойя.

Comment: (Майя/секвойя кстати, в беглой речи произносятся как 'мая/секвоя' - 'j' выделяются только когда собеседник совсем не готов услышать что-то такое, и не готов отличить Майя от мая). Просто записать неудачный оборот, вопросов никаких, выше вы сами это вполне внятно сделали уже: *... довелось услышать окказионализм "предъюбилей-е" ....* Никаких "предъюбилейе, Заалтайе" же *без кавычек* нет, и быть не может в принципе.

Comment: Соответственно и записывать такие "слова" можно *как угодно*, просто в силу отсутствия каких-либо норм как таковых: "Заалтайе", "Заалтае", "Заалтаее", "Заалтаиьэ" - все будет одинаково "неправильно". Но цель-то основная в том чтобы донести смысл сказанного, так? "Орфография" тут вообще никаким боком на мой взгляд (и Майя с секвойей в данном случае плохие советчики, потому что ни то, ни другое не есть Май+я/секвой+я, хотя второе и склоняется по очевидным причинам).

Comment: к фонетическим контраргументам можно добавить то, что фонема **е** из суффикса **-ье** состоит из двух звуков **й+э**, таким образом даже если исключить нагромождение мягкого знака на мягкий **Й**, всё равно получаем сдвоенный звук **йй = й + йэ**, что само по себе издевательство над фонетикой русского языка... я думаю искать надо в области способов замены или дополнения **Й** переходными фонемами, что-то наподобие **Заалтайстье** или **Заалтавье**

Answer (score 6):

Такого слова нет. Наличие горной системы не предполагает автоматически, что существует образованное от него слово с приставкой "за-". В случае Закавказья мы имеем исторически обосабливаемый регион, поэтому существование отдельного термина оправданно.

Урал условно делит Россию на ту часть, что была в Русском царстве и ту, что стала российской на этапе Российской Империи.

То же самое с Закарпатьем или, например, с Припамирьем.

Территории за Алтаем же обособленного культурного, экономического или исторического единства всё-таки не составляли, поэтому слова типа Заалтайщина просто не случилось - нечего им было обозначать.

Есть территории Монголии, Китая и Казахстана.

Comment: Казахстан это скорее "Приалтайщина", чем "Заалтайщина".

Answer (score 2):

If you must, you can use generic `загорье`.